# jQuery._data event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to determine whether Twitter Bootstrap "tab.js" has been loaded. One way is to look at the events that it hooks.

If I dump the event handlers to the console:

```
var ii;
var docEvents = jQuery._data(document, "events");
var docClickEvents = docEvents.click;
console.log("docEvents: %O", docEvents);
console.log("docClickEvents: %O", docClickEvents);
console.log("docClickEvents.length: %O", docClickEvents.length);
for (ii = 0; ii < 7; ii += 1) {
    console.log("docClickEvents[%d].namespace=%O", ii, docClickEvents[ii].namespace);
}
```

Chrome's console shows:

[Chrome console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc5fj.png)

As you can see the click Array[7] becomes an Array[5] but 7 objects are displayed, and then when I try to display the namespace of element [5], elements [5] and [6] have disappeared!

Anyone know what's happening here, and how to read the value of element [5], being

```
namespace:"bs.data-api.tab"
```

Thanks
JC

Comment: `if (typeof $.fn.tabs === "function") { /* tab.js is available */ }`

Comment: Sadly, Bootstrap tab.js adds 'tab' rather than 'tabs' and

    $.fn.tab 

is always undefined. Testing for it doesn't determine whether 'tab.js' is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It was a timing problem. I was loading 'tab.js', appending it to the body, and assuming this process would complete immediately:

```
ourScript = document.createElement("script");
ourScript.type  = "text/javascript";
ourScript.src = sourceDir + "tab.js";
document.body.appendChild(ourScript);
```

There appears to be no callback from jquery appends, so I added a one second time delay before checking for 'tab.js' and all seems OK. I expect the Chrome console gets confused and shows strange effects.

Final code:

```
// ---------------------------------
var eventNameSpaceLoaded = function (thisNamespace) {
    var isLoaded = false;
    var theseClickEvents = jQuery._data(document, "events").click; 

    Object.keys(theseClickEvents).forEach(function (key) {
        if (theseClickEvents[key].namespace && (theseClickEvents[key].namespace === thisNamespace)) {
            isLoaded = true;
            return false;               // stop the each
        }
    });
    return isLoaded;
};

// check bootstrap tab.js is loaded
var ourScript;
if( !eventNameSpaceLoaded("bs.data-api.tab")) {
    ourScript = document.createElement("script");
    ourScript.type = "text/javascript";
    ourScript.src = sourceDir + "tab.js";
    document.body.appendChild(ourScript);
}

// has tab.js been loaded - try checking for 10 seconds
(function checkTabLoad( counter) {
    if( !eventNameSpaceLoaded("bs.data-api.tab")) {
        counter -= 1;
        if(counter > 0){
            setTimeout(function(){  
                checkTabLoad( counter); 
            }, 100);
        }
    } else {
        // get tabs working 
        $('#SOME_ SELECTOR').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).tab('show');
        });
        console.log("tabs fired up");
    }
}( 100));
```